# Spring Data REST making range check with QueryDSL binding

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I have request like this:

http://localhost:4000/services/querywithdsl?min=30&max=90

My domain entity only consists of id :

```
@Entity
@Data
public class ServiceNumberPorting {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;
}
```

And my rest controller with predicate

```
@GetMapping(value = "/services/querywithdsl")
    public ResponseEntity<List<ServiceNumberPortingMapper>>getServiceNumberPortingWithDsl(@QuerydslPredicate(root = ServiceNumberPorting.class) Predicate predicate) {
        ...

    }
```

Repository:

```
public interface ServiceNumberPortingRepository extends JpaRepository<ServiceNumberPorting, Long>,QuerydslPredicateExecutor<ServiceNumberPorting>,    QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QServiceNumberPorting>
```

***I want to build query with querydsl like this one using bindings***

```
..where id>min and id< max
```

**All examples I found are directly mapping query parameters to entity column, but in this example, I have only id in my entity and I want to do range check with incoming parameter values which have different name than my entity columns.**

However, since my domain won't consist of min and max columns I could't get it working with customizing binding such as using QueryDslBinderCustomizer:

```
bindings.bind(store.city).single((path, value) -> path.endsWith(value));
```

How to accomplish that?

*Here is docs that I gone through:
[spring data examples](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/blob/querydsl-binding/rest/starbucks/src/main/java/example/stores/StoreRepository.java) 
[binding examples](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.springframework.data.querydsl.binding.QuerydslBindings)*

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48596145/5380322) is an approach (see 'between filter').

Comment: you are using profile.heightMeters which probably exists in Profile entity. But min and max properties do not exist in my entity. How do I compare them with id?

Comment: But you have property `id` - when you implement this approach you will get 'between' 30 and 90 filter for `id` like this: `/services/?id=30&id=90`

Comment: @sarah did my solution work for you?

Comment: I ended up using some dto object to map request fields to object and creating dsl query myself with pageable repository. Not quite what I looked for to be honest. But I thank you both for solutions and your time, learned new approaches from those answers.

Comment: i am in the same situation, any workaround?

Comment: @Andres I ended up with classic approach, some dummy object for holding query parameters(mapping incoming request directly to this object), then some repository which extending QuerydslPredicateExecutor. Then I build Predicate object and querying with this repository which supports predicate as an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the solutions I can think of is this:

In your repository,I have defined a method `getValueLyingBetween` and written a simple query:

```
public interface ServiceNumberPortingRepository extends JpaRepository...{
    @Query("SELECT m FROM <YOUR_TABLE_NAME> m where ( m.id >=:min and m.id <= :max )")
    public ServiceNumberPorting getValueLyingBetween(@Param("min") String min, @Param("max") String max);

}
```

And then you can simply call this repository method from your controller with min and max values.

Is this what you were looking for?