# Spring data JPA method name query

Tags: spring-data-jpa

For example a user repository,

```
interface PersonRepository extends Repository<User, Long> {      
   List<Person> findByEmailAddressAndLastname(EmailAddress emailAddress, String lastname); 
}
```

Is there a way to achieve `findByEmailAddressAndLastname(null, "lastname")` = `findByLastname("lastname")`, because after I add more parameters in user entity, the number of method name query increase exponentially. I want to reduce the redundancy.
Thanks.

Comment: your question is unclear. do you mind explaining, what do you meant by `findByEmailAddressAndLastname(null, "lastname") = findByLastname("lastname")`

Comment: @pvpkiran If I pass a null parameter, I want the method to return all entity without filtering that parameter.

Comment: @JasminDan if you have many properties and you need to have filter on them IMO it's better to use QueryDsl: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48596145

Comment: Check [`@Query`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query) which will help you to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Since spring-data-jpa 2 you can use [@Nullable](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/lang/Nullable.html) annotation:

```
   List<Person> findByEmailAddressAndLastname(@Nullable EmailAddress emailAddress, String lastname);
```

Check [nullability annotations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.nullability.annotations) to see all the variants

Comment: If I pass a null parameter, does it compare entity parameter with null value or just does not compare it at all?

Comment: if you pass a null parameter the query will be "emailAddress is null". To achieve your approach i suggest that use find by example from JpaRepository:
 List<S> findAll(Example<S> example);
like this:
User user = new User();
user.setEmailAddress (emailAddress); 
user.setLastName(lastname);
List<Usr> results = personRepository.findAll(Example.of(user));