# spring data jpa multiple dynamic criteria search

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I am looking for the best way (or pro/con of different methods) to do a search with multiple dynamic criteria. It means that the number of search criteria might be different.
I have found some method in spring:

- MethodNameQuery (fixed number of criteria)
- `@Query`(fixed number of criteria)
- Specification
- Querydsl
- ExampleMatcher

Are there other options that I didn't list?
Which one should I use in spring boot with spring data JPA?
How to perform `IN` search with ExampleMatcher.

Thanks.

Comment: IMO QueryDsl is the right choice: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48596145

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic spring data jpa repository query with arbitrary AND clauses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28874135/dynamic-spring-data-jpa-repository-query-with-arbitrary-and-clauses)