# Combine JpaRepository with QueryDslPredicateExecutor

Tags: design-patterns, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

Is there a good design pattern that allows a single interface to combine the methods of Spring Data and Query DSL so that the query dsl methods are declared in a separated class and all that without having to deal directly with the EntityManager.
Thanks

Comment: May be my answer will be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48596145

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best design pattern that I found is this one :
[JpaRepository & Query DSL Combination](https://gist.github.com/arthurportas/eb3f722c3c8194b52e78)

It consist in two interfaces : the first one extends jpaRepository and the second interface, plus the implementation of this last one who extends QueryDslRepositorySupport.