# Spring boot with Spring data JPA -Q classes cannot be resolved

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Please can anyone knows solution how to resolve -Q class generation and tried with below version-

querydsl -4.1.4,3.7.2,3.7.3
and used apt-maven-plugin-1.1.3

Comment: May be my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48596145/5380322) will be helpful...

Comment: Please, could you post your pom.xml? Generally it is a problem with the Processor Class declared in the apt-maven-plugin.