# Implement complex search feature using Spring BOOT REST and Spring Data JPA using Criteria API

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api, spring-rest

I need to implement complex search feature using *Spring Boot REST* and *Spring Data JPA* using Criteria API. I need to provide RPIs like below
`/college?select=*&where=name:DemoCollege` and `location:LA` and `staff{firstName:foo, lastName:boo, workExp>10}` and type in **[1,2,3]**

Collage object has `name`, `location`, `type` fields and `staff` list. 
It has `onetomany` relationship with `Staff` so `College` can have one or many Staff members.

based on the uri I need to build query using criteria api.

I am finding it very complex to implement the `toPredicate()` method of `org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification`. Is there any such example handing such complex search filters?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I think the best choice, in your case, is the [specification-arg-resolver](https://github.com/tkaczmarzyk/specification-arg-resolver) lib that provide convenient way to build specification declaratively. For example, this code:

```java
@RequestMapping("/customers")
public Object findByName(
        @And({
            @Spec(path="registrationDate", params="registeredBefore", spec=DateBefore.class),
            @Spec(path="lastName", spec=Like.class)}) Specification<Customer> customerSpec) {

    return customerRepo.findAll(customerSpec);
}
```

is corresponding to this request:

```
GET http://myhost/customers?registeredBefore=2015-01-18&lastName=Simpson
```

It supports the following specifications: Like, LikeIgnoreCase, Equal, EqualIgnoreCase, In, Null, NotNull, GreaterThan, GreaterThanOrEqual, LessThan, LessThanOrEqual, DateBetween, Join, Join fetch, and it allows you to combine them, composing complex expressions.

---

Another option is [Querydsl](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/#core.extensions.querydsl) and [Web support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web) Spring Data extensions. It also allows you to build a 'REST query language' but has fewer possibilities. You can read in my answer how to use it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48596145