# Passing dynamic queries in spring JPA

Tags: spring, jdbc, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, repository

I want to know how do we pass a query in spring JPA that has been prepared dynamically while program execution. The required query may vary according to the user input. So after framing the query manually using a for loop how do i execute this query ?

I have tried executing the query using the JDBC concept. but i want something more like :

```
@Query ( query_String)
public <return_type> filterNodes(String query_String);
```

Is this possible ?

Comment: Please see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50650237

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28874135/dynamic-spring-data-jpa-repository-query-with-arbitrary-and-clauses

Answer (score 1):

The approach you sketched does not work.

Depending on how you create the query there are various options that might fit the bill:

- [Query by Example](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#query-by-example) is quite limited but has it's uses
- [Specifications or their Querydsl equivalent](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/) are rather flexible and I'd expect them to work in your case but that is just guessing since you don't describe how you create your query.
- If everything fails you can write a [custom method implementation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations) that takea s the query as parameter and uses an `EntityManager` to execute it.