# How to easy implement 'REST API query language' with Querydsl and Spring Data to filter the entities?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-data, querydsl

How to easy implement a kind of 'REST API query language' with **Spring Data** to filter the entities?

For example, for the following `Person` entity:

```java
@Data
@Entity
public class Person {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  private LocalDate dob; // date of birth

  private String name;

  @Formula("timestampdiff('year', dob, now())")
  private Integer age;

  public Person(String name, LocalDate dob) {
    this.name = name;
    this.dob = dob;
  }
}
```

I would like to get its data with such a request:

```
GET /people?name=jo&age=18&page=1&sort=name,desc
```

I.e.: 'get the 1st page of all people whose `name` contains "jo" (case insensitive) and whose `age` is equal to 18, sorting by `name` in descending order'.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

With help of [Querydsl Web Support](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web.type-safe), the part of [Web support Spring Data extension](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#core.web), we can easy implement a kind of 'REST API query language' to filter our entities.

All we need is do the following:

1) extend our repository from `QuerydslPredicateExecutor`,

2) add `Predicate` with annotation `@QuerydslPredicate`, as argument, to our REST controller method

3) use this predicate in `findAll` method of the repository:

```java
public interface PersonRepo extends JpaRepository<Person, Long>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Person> {
}
```

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/people")
public class PersonController {

    private final PersonRepo personRepo;

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity getFiltered(@QuerydslPredicate(root = Person.class) Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(personRepo.findAll(predicate, pageable)));
    }
}
```

Then we will be able to request our data:

```
GET /people?name=John&age=18&page=1&sort=name,desc
```

Next we have to make case insensitive 'like' filter. To do this we extend our repo from `QuerydslBinderCustomizer` and override its `customize` method (right in the repo):

```java
public interface PersonRepo extends
        JpaRepository<Person, Long>,
        QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Person>,
        QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QPerson> {

    @Override
    default void customize(QuerydslBindings bindings, QPerson person) {

        // Make case-insensitive 'like' filter for all string properties 
        bindings.bind(String.class).first((SingleValueBinding<StringPath, String>) StringExpression::containsIgnoreCase);
    }
}
```

To make it works we have to add parameter `bindings` to `@QuerydslPredicate` of our controller method:

```java
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity getFiltered(
    @QuerydslPredicate(root = Person.class, bindings = PersonRepo.class) Predicate predicate, 
    Pageable pageable
) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(personRepo.findAll(predicate, pageable)));
}
```

Now we can request our data as asked in the question:

```
GET /people?name=jo&age=18&page=1&sort=name,desc
```

With `QuerydslBinderCustomizer` we can implement more complex filters, for example `between` and `greater or equal` filters (add this code to `customize` method):

```java
bindings.bind(person.age).all((path, value) -> {
    Iterator<? extends Integer> it = value.iterator();
    Integer from = it.next();
    if (value.size() >= 2) {
        Integer to = it.next();
        return Optional.of(path.between(from, to)); // between
    } else {
        return Optional.of(path.goe(from)); // greater or equal
    }
});
```

If we specify two `age` parameters in the request then we get all records with the age **between** these parameters. If we specify only one `age` parameter - we get records with the age is greater or equal that value.

```
GET /people?age=18&age=30
```

... *get all people with the age between 18 and 30*

```
GET /people?age=18
```

... *get all people with the age is greater or equal than 18*

In the end we can exclude some unnecessary properties from the filter, for example the entity `id` (add this code to `customize` method):

```
bindings.excluding(person.id);
```

To use Querydsl Web Support we have to add these dependencies and plugin to our Spring Boot project:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <!-- ... -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- ... -->

        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/annotations</outputDirectory>
                        <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Then, it's important, **compile the project** to build 'Q-classes' of our entities.

Full example demo you can find in my repo: [sb-querydsl-sd-demo](https://github.com/Cepr0/sb-querydsl-sd-demo), and [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) API-docs of this demo - here: [REST query language with Querydsl and Spring Data](https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/788154/RWEnmvWX).

Comment: If "GET /people?age=18" returns all people which are 18 or older. How to get all people with the age of 18? Like that "GET /people?age=18&age=18"?

Comment: @SvenDöring yes, you are right. Perhaps my other posts on this subject will also be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55761257, https://stackoverflow.com/a/55978161

Comment: How do you implement both EQUALS and LIKE operators?

Answer (score 0):

QueryDSL Web support is a good option but it's hard to customize when it comes to more specific field as explained [here](https://adrian.md/2023/01/07/querydsl-rsql/).
Instead you can use a `rsql-querydsl` that offers more liberty in terms of supported operators and some other advantages.

First add the library to you POM:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.github.apulbere</groupId>
  <artifactId>rsql-querydsl</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Then define a DTO that will represent your search criteria. Notice that this is DTO and not the entity itself, which helps to keep persistence layer separate from the view:

```
@Setter
@Getter
public class PersonCriteria {
   StringCriteria name = StringCriteria.empty();
   LongCriteria age = LongCriteria.empty();
}
```

And finally build the predicate. Note that you can do the mapping between your search DTO and Q model as you wish which offers more flexibility of how you REST API looks:

```
@GetMapping("/people")
List<PersonDTO> search(PersonCriteria criteria, Pageable page) {
    var predicate = criteria.age.match(QPerson.age)
            .and(criteria.name.match(QPerson.name));
    return peopleRepository.findAll(predicate, page)
            .stream()
            .map(personMapper::map)
            .toList();
}
```