# Implement search filter with conditions

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I want to implement search functionality with several sub conditions. I tried this:

```
    @GetMapping("find")
    public Page<PaymentTransactionsDTO> getAllBySpecification(
            @And({
                    @Spec(path = "name", spec = LikeIgnoreCase.class),
                    @Spec(path = "unique_id", spec = LikeIgnoreCase.class),
                    @Spec(path = "createdAt", params = "from", spec = GreaterThanOrEqual.class),
                    @Spec(path = "createdAt", params = "to", spec = LessThanOrEqual.class)
            }) Specification<PaymentTransactions> specification,
            Pageable pageable
    ) {        
        return transactionService.getAllBySpecification(specification, pageable));       
    }
```

Repository:

```
      @Override
      public Page<PaymentTransactions> getAllBySpecification(final Specification<PaymentTransactions> specification, final Pageable pageable) {
          return dao.findAll(specification, pageable);
      }
```

Currently this request is working:

```
GET /api/transactions/find?unique_id=22&page=0&size=10
```

But also I want to implement these additional search conditions not only sending basic search for `unique_id`:

```
start with 
=
end with 
contains
```

Using https://github.com/tkaczmarzyk/specification-arg-resolver is there some way to send additional sub conditions? I can't find a solution for this issue in general what are the best practices to send these values?

Comment: I recommend you not to handle this on the method definition level using annotations but let all the parameter pass and implement a logic or expression language validator to handle the possible combinations.

Comment: @Nikolas Thanks you for the reply. Can you show me code example, please?

Comment: Have you tried to write some code first?

Comment: See the above code that I tried to implement. I'm not aware how to Specification for the above case.

Comment: I pointed out that I don't recommend you to continue the way using annotations and I suggested you implement a different mechanism. Please, read carefully.

Comment: ok, can you give me some code example to clearly see what is the proper way to implement it, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to create your very special filter I believe you should start with invention of your search interface. For example like that:

```
GET /models?name=eq(john smith)&createdAt=between(2019-01-01,2019-01-31)
GET /models?name=like(sm)&createdAt=from(2019-01-01)
GET /models?name=sw(john)&createdAt=to(2019-01-31)
```

After that, you will be able to try to implement it.

IMO the best way to solve such a task is to use Spring Data JPA [Specifications](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/) (and JPA Criteria API). For example:

1) Let's create a `Filter` class that implements `Specification` for our entity `Model`:

```java
@Value
public class ModelFilter implements Specification<Model> {

    private String name;
    private String createdAt;

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Model> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {

        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

        // Prepare predicates and fill the list with them...

        return builder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    }
}
```

2) Then create a controller method:

```java
@GetMapping
public List<Model> getAllByFilter(ModelFilter filter) {
    return repo.findAll(filter); 
}
```

All that's left to do is prepare our predicates ))

To make this, we can create a handy 'Predicate Builder' interface first:

```java
@FunctionalInterface
interface PredicateBuilder<T> {

    Optional<Predicate> get(String fieldName, String value, Root<T> root, CriteriaBuilder builder);

    static Matcher getMatcher(String op, String value) {
        return getMatcher(op, value, "(.+)");
    }

    static Matcher getMatcher(String op, String value, String pattern) {
        return Pattern.compile(op + "\\(" + pattern + "\\)").matcher(value);
    }
}
```

Then try to make our predicates:

**equal**

```java
PredicateBuilder<Model> eq = (fieldName, value, root, cb) -> {
    Matcher m = getMatcher("eq", value);
    if (m.matches()) {
        return Optional.of(cb.equal(cb.upper(root.get(fieldName)), m.group(1).toUpperCase()));
    } else {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
};
```

**like**

```java
PredicateBuilder<Model> like = (fn, value, root, cb) -> {
    Matcher m = getMatcher("like", value);
    if (m.matches()) {
        return Optional.of(cb.like(cb.upper(root.get(fn)), "%" + m.group(1).toUpperCase() + "%"));
    } else {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
};
```

**start with**

```java
PredicateBuilder<Model> sw = (fn, value, root, cb) -> {
    Matcher m = getMatcher("sw", value);
    if (m.matches()) {
        return Optional.of(cb.like(cb.upper(root.get(fn)), m.group(1).toUpperCase() + "%"));
    } else {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
};
```

**between**

```java
PredicateBuilder<Model> between = (fn, value, root, cb) -> {
    Matcher m = getMatcher("between", value, "(.+)\\s*,\\s*(.+)");
    if (m.matches()) {
        LocalDate from = LocalDate.parse(m.group(1));
        LocalDate to = LocalDate.parse(m.group(2));
        return Optional.of(cb.between(root.get(fn), from, to));
    } else {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
};
```

**from**

```java
PredicateBuilder<Model> from = (fn, value, root, cb) -> {
    Matcher m = getMatcher("from", value);
    if (m.matches()) {
        LocalDate from = LocalDate.parse(m.group(1));
        return Optional.of(cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get(fn), from));
    } else {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
};
```

**to**

```java
PredicateBuilder<Model> to = (fn, value, root, cb) -> {
    Matcher m = getMatcher("to", value);
    if (m.matches()) {
        LocalDate to = LocalDate.parse(m.group(1));
        return Optional.of(cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get(fn), to));
    } else {
        return Optional.empty();
    }
};
```

It remains only to complete the `Filter` class:

```java
@Value
public class ModelFilter implements Specification<Model> {

    private String name;
    private String createdAt;

    PredicateBuilder<Model> eq = ... ;
    PredicateBuilder<Model> like = ... ;
    PredicateBuilder<Model> sw = ... ;
    PredicateBuilder<Model> between = ... ;
    PredicateBuilder<Model> from = ... ;
    PredicateBuilder<Model> to = ... ;

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Model> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {

        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

        if (name != null) {
            eq.get("name", name, root, builder).ifPresent(predicates::add);
            like.get("name", name, root, builder).ifPresent(predicates::add);
            sw.get("name", name, root, builder).ifPresent(predicates::add);
        }

        if (createdAt != null) {
            between.get("createdAt", createdAt, root, builder).ifPresent(predicates::add);
            from.get("createdAt", createdAt, root, builder).ifPresent(predicates::add);
            to.get("createdAt", createdAt, root, builder).ifPresent(predicates::add);
        }

        return builder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
    }
}
```

Of course it's just one example of implementation. You can create your very own implementation of specifications and predicates you need. The main things here are:

- come up with your search interface
- make your 'filter' Specification
- prepare all the predicates you need
- use the filter specification in your controller method

Comment: I have a question. Do you know is there other search framework which can be used to implement the above functionality more easy?

Comment: Usually how do you implement search logic in complex projects?

Comment: @PeterPenzov What do you mean?

Comment: If you have a complex search filter for some DB table in order to make complex queries like the above example what do you use?

Comment: @PeterPenzov I think you can choose every option you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55761257

Comment: I have a question. I tried to extend JPA Specification but I get NPE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57317139/nullpointerexception-when-building-custom-specification Any idea why?