# How to add a comparator to querydsl Predicate?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest, querydsl

I have the following webservice the automatically translates get parameter queries to database selects:

```
public interface PersonRepo extends
        JpaRepository<Person, Long>,
        QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Person> {

}

@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity getFiltered(
    @QuerydslPredicate(root = Person.class) Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable) {
       return ResponseEntity.ok(personRepo.findAll(predicate, pageable)));
    )
}
```

The following queries could eg be executed:

```
GET /people?name=John&age=18
GET /people?name=John&age=18&page=1&sort=name,desc
```

Problem: I want to apply comparator queries as follows:

```
GET /people?name=John&age>18
GET /people?name=John&age>18&age<30
GET /people?name=John&age<30
```

Question: how could I achieve this? At least the later queries don't work.

Comment: Spring Data doesn't support such queries. You can customize the bindings (and use aliases e.g. agegt=18) https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-search-querydsl-web-in-spring-data-jpa but an OData (Olingo) or GraphQL implementation might be better for flexible queries such as this.

Comment: Could you give an example on using eg `agegt`? Because that would be a property that I don't have on my `Person.class`, so how can I get it into the `QPerson.class` then?

Comment: @membersound please check my posts ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55761257), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55978161)), hope they'll be helpful. Regarding your second question, if `Person` has an association with another entity, for example `Data` that contains `age` property, try to address it with prefix `data.`, for example: `data.age`, maybe it'll help you. Nevertheless, as @AlanHay already said, Querydsl isn't the best solution for your task, IMO it's better to use Specifications/Criteria API to build your own 'query language' (see my 2nd link).

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution by defining a placeholder for the field, and using a `QuerydslBinderCustomizer`:

```
public interface PersonRepo extends
        JpaRepository<Person, Long>,
        QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Person>,
        QuerydslBinderCustomizer<Person> {
    default void customize(final QuerydslBindings bindings, final QPerson person) {
        bindings.bind(cache.ageMin).first((path, value) -> person.age.goe(value));
        bindings.bind(cache.ageMax).first((path, value) -> person.age.loe(value));
    }
}
```

Of course the age fields then have to exist as transient fields, so that querydsl knows them:

```
@Entity
class Person {
    @Transient
    @QueryType(PropertyType.NUMERIC)
    public int ageMin;

    @Transient
    @QueryType(PropertyType.NUMERIC)
    private int ageMax;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a single binding and use expressions from [Query DSL value operators](https://gt-tech.bitbucket.io/spring-data-querydsl-value-operators/README.html).

```
public interface PersonRepo extends
    JpaRepository<Person, Long>,
    QuerydslPredicateExecutor<Person>,
    QuerydslBinderCustomizer<Person> {
    default void customize(final QuerydslBindings bindings, final QPerson person) {
        bindings.bind(cache.age).all((path, values) -> ExpressionProviderFactory.getPredicate(path, values));
    }
}
```