# Create Dynamic JPA Query

Tags: java, spring, dynamic, spring-data-jpa

I have a view with many fields as query filters, and I am using JPA derived queries , however creating all queries for every combination of fields/filters would be tedious and long.

I found out that I can create a dynamic query for it, but not sure how.

So far I have created these queries in my repository, but still need a lot more :

```
 public interface EmployeeReportInfoViewRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<EmployeeReportInfo, Long> {

 List<EmployeeReportInfo> findByControlNumber(String controlNmber);

 List<EmployeeReportInfo> findByManager(String manager);

 List<EmployeeReportInfo> findByofficeLocation(String officeLocation);

 List<EmployeeReportInfo> findByBenchFlag(char benchFlag);

 List<EmployeeReportInfo> findByBillableFlag(char billableFlag);

 List<EmployeeReportInfo> findByEnableFlag(boolean enableFlag);

 List<EmployeeReportInfo> findByLastNameAndFirstNameAndControlNumber(String lastName, String firstName,String controlNumber);

 List<EmployeeReportInfo> findByLastNameAndFirstNameAndControlNumberAndManager(String lastName, String firstName,String controlNmber,String manager);

 List<EmployeeReportInfo> findByLastNameAndFirstNameAndControlNumberAndManagerAndOfficeLocation(String lastName, String firstName,String controlNmber,String manager,String officeLocation);

 List<EmployeeReportInfo> findByLastNameAndFirstNameAndControlNumberAndManagerAndOfficeLocationAndBenchFlag(String lastName, String firstName,String controlNmber,String manager,String officeLocation, char benchFlag);

 List<EmployeeReportInfo> findByLastNameAndFirstNameAndControlNumberAndManagerAndOfficeLocationAndBenchFlagAndBillableFlag(String lastName, String firstName,String controlNmber,String manager,String officeLocation, char benchFlag,char bllableFlag);

 List<EmployeeReportInfo> findByLastNameAndFirstNameAndControlNumberAndManagerAndOfficeLocationAndBenchFlagAndBillableFlagAndEnableFlagAndStartGreaterThanEqualAndEndLessThanEqual
 (String lastName, String firstName,String controlNmber,String manager,String officeLocation, char benchFlag,char bllableFlag, 
         boolean emableFlag, Date start,Date end); 


}

@Entity
@Table(name = "employee_report_view")
public class EmployeeReportInfo {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "employee_id")
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private Date start;

    private Date end;

    @Column(name = "control_number")
    private String controlNumber;

    @Column(name = "enable_flag")
    private boolean enableFlag;

    @Column(name = "billable_flag")
    private char billableFlag;

    @Column(name = "bench_flag")
    private char benchFlag;

    @Column(name = "office_location")
    private String officeLocation;

    @Column(name = "manager")
    private String manager;

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @param id the id to set
     */
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    /**
     * @return the start
     */
    public Date getStart() {
        return start;
    }

    /**
     * @param start the start to set
     */
    public void setStart(Date start) {
        this.start = start;
    }

    /**
     * @return the end
     */
    public Date getEnd() {
        return end;
    }

    /**
     * @param end the end to set
     */
    public void setEnd(Date end) {
        this.end = end;
    }

    /**
     * @return the controlNumber
     */
    public String getControlNumber() {
        return controlNumber;
    }

    /**
     * @param controlNumber the controlNumber to set
     */
    public void setControlNumber(String controlNumber) {
        this.controlNumber = controlNumber;
    }

    /**
     * @return the enableFlag
     */
    public boolean isEnableFlag() {
        return enableFlag;
    }

    /**
     * @param enableFlag the enableFlag to set
     */
    public void setEnableFlag(boolean enableFlag) {
        this.enableFlag = enableFlag;
    }

    /**
     * @return the billableFlag
     */
    public char getBillableFlag() {
        return billableFlag;
    }

    /**
     * @param billableFlag the billableFlag to set
     */
    public void setBillableFlag(char billableFlag) {
        this.billableFlag = billableFlag;
    }

    /**
     * @return the benchFlag
     */
    public char getBenchFlag() {
        return benchFlag;
    }

    /**
     * @param benchFlag the benchFlag to set
     */
    public void setBenchFlag(char benchFlag) {
        this.benchFlag = benchFlag;
    }

    /**
     * @return the officeLocation
     */
    public String getOfficeLocation() {
        return officeLocation;
    }

    /**
     * @param officeLocation the officeLocation to set
     */
    public void setOfficeLocation(String officeLocation) {
        this.officeLocation = officeLocation;
    }

    /**
     * @return the manager
     */
    public String getManager() {
        return manager;
    }

    /**
     * @param manager the manager to set
     */
    public void setManager(String manager) {
        this.manager = manager;
    }

}
```

[image: Employees Report]

Comment: So what is the question? Do you need to know how to run custom sql queries rather than JPA in Spring?

Comment: I need to be able to run dynamic query , for example , I can search  and filter by name from my form, or search by name and manager, or manager and office and controlnumber,or by start date and manager .... and so on

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering data with Spring boot CrudRepository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33646714/filtering-data-with-spring-boot-crudrepository)

Comment: Try to use the following approaches: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55761257/5380322), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55978161/5380322)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can understand your needs:you want to dynamically generate query conditions based on the url issued by the form.Let's assume that the url maps to the back end to a `HashMap<String,String>`.

For instance,url:

```
127.0.0.1/employees?nameContains=jack&ageEquals=10
```

Map:

```
HashMap<String, String>:key:nameContains,value:jack,key:ageEuqals,value:10
```

The Spring framework can do this mapping automatically(`RequestParamMapMethodArgumentResolver`). What you need to do is to dynamically generate the Specification([Specification](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications)) by this map.

1. Gets the type of property corresponding to the field using reflect : name=>String, age=>Integer
2. Using CriteriaBuilder to build query criteria,it has comprehensive api,such as:

> Predicate like(Expression x, String pattern);    => contains
>
> Predicate equal(Expression x, Expression y);    => equal

3. Assemble your query criteria(or,and)
4. You get a Specification.

This is a relatively complex solution idea, which requires the coordination between the front table component and the back end, but it will be very convenient.

What I said is relatively simple and general, there are a lot of details.(such as nested properties,one-to-one,one-to-many,etc)

Also,You can have a look http://www.querydsl.com/