# Spring Data Rest - Configure findBy path

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

With the following Repository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "people", path = "people")
public interface PeopleRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<People, String> {

    @RestResource
    List<People> findByName(@Param("name") String name);

}
```

URL for `findByName` is automatically set to `/people/search/findByName`. But it seems quite verbose, can the URL be configured to `/people` and query is like `/people?name=john` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the QueryDSL extension you can have the query in that format and have the additional benefit of being able to filter by any combination of properties without having to write any query methods:

**Configuration (Assuming Maven)**

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId> 
    <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId> 
    <version>4.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency> 
    <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId> 
    <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId> 
    <version>4.1.4</version> 
</dependency>
```

Then simply update your repository definition:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "people", path = "people")
public interface PeopleRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<People, String>, 
                                               QuerydslPredicateExecutor<People> {


}
```

You should now be able to filter like:

```
/people?name=john
/people?name=John&address.town=London
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

You can change the last part of the path (see the [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_paging)):

```java
@RestResource(path = "byName", rel = "byName")
List<People> findByName(@Param("name") String name);
```

```
/people/search/byName?name=john
```

For comprehensive implementation with QueryDsl see @AlanHay answer (more info is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48596145/5380322))